# Revel Framework - Go Lang - Not able to find controller

Tags: go, revel

I am using Revel framework for golang. I have a subdirectory in my controllers folder like below

```
controllers
   new
     app2.go
   app1.go
```

Contents of app1.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
)

type APP1 struct {
    *revel.Controller
}
func (c APP1) Show() revel.Result {
}
```

Contents of app2.go

```
import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
)

type APP2 struct {
    *revel.Controller
}
func (c APP2) Show() revel.Result {
}
```

My routes file is like this

```
GET     /v1/show              APP1.show
GET     /v2/show              APP2.show
```

When I call /v2/show it gives me error failed to find controller APP2 while v1/show is working absolutely working fine. Can anybody tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the route for APP2.show like this `GET   /new/v2/show`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below at the top of `app2.go`

```
package controllers
```

I tried the same using a similar example and it worked for me. I would suggest not to use full capitalized controller names; use `App2` instead of `APP2`.

Answer (score 0):

I was a little confused to find out that the methods referenced from the router need to be Pascal Cased to be recognized (e.g. like above `func (c APP2) DescribeService() revel.Result`).  This might be obvious to seasoned Revel or Go developers but really wasn't obvious to me.